# Select all except one field in cakephp 3 query

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I just want to select all fields except one field in cakephp 3.

```
Ex. $this->select('fname', 'lname', 'mname', 'email', 'password', 'status', 'created', 'modified');
```

Here i want to select all fields except created and modified because my other table have apprx 30 fields and i want to select 28 fields and don't want to mentioned each and every field in select function because it is time consuming.

Can you please suggest a better way.

Answer (score 5):

As of CakePHP 3.6 the `selectAllExcept()` method has been introduced, which will select all columns from the schema that belongs to the given table, except those columns passed in the second argument:

```
$query->selectAllExcept($table, ['modified', 'created']);
```

In earlier versions you'd have to do that manually, ie grab all the possible columns from the schema and remove those that you don't want to include, like:

```
$query->select(
    array_diff($table->schema()->columns(), ['modified', 'created']);
);
```

On a related note, check the following issue that asks for a deselect functionality: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6904**

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Specific Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-specific-fields)**

Answer (score 2):

You could just find all and then at runtime hide what you dont need

```
$model->hiddenProperties(['modified', 'created']);
```