# SELECT query excluding columns in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a database table with the following columns:

- id
- country_id
- name
- email

I want to select all the columns, excluding `id` and `country_id` in a `SELECT` query.

I have tried the following:

```
$getOldvalue = $myTable->find()->where(['country_id' => 10])->first()->toArray();
$notAllow = ['id','country_id'];
foreach ($notAllow as $no) {
    if(($key = array_search($no, array_keys($getOldvalue))) !== false) {
        unset(array_keys($getOldvalue)[$key]);
    }
}
```

This returns `id` and `country_id`. How do I select all columns without `id` and `country_id`?

Comment: i want like NOT SELECT

Comment: Could you post some sample table data so we can see what you're working with, as well as examples of expected outcome?

Comment: Improved English and formatting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719618/select-all-except-one-field-in-cakephp-3-query

Answer (score 2):

To limit the fields fetched, you can use the `select()` method, like below:

```
$getOldvalue = $myTable->find()->select(['name','email'])->where(['country_id' => 10])->first()->toArray();
```

for more details [see documentation here.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)
I hope this will work for you.

Comment: but problem is that some this table have dynamic columns so know only two columns id and country_id who is fixed.

Comment: You could build a list of dynamic columns, adding in name and email, to pass to the select function. Or you could just get everything and simply not use the id and country_id. What's the reason that you don't want to select those two? If you're trying to make it faster by loading only the columns you'll need, there's almost no chance that the difference is going to be noticeable.