# CakePHP 3 - Exclude fields by default in query unless specifically selected

Tags: select, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

Title pretty much says it all. I have some tables with fields that contain a lot of data. To save some performance I would like to not SELECT these by default.
The emphasis on the new default behaviour, differentiating the question from e.g. [Select all except one field in cakephp 3 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719618/select-all-except-one-field-in-cakephp-3-query)

Example:

```
$cities = $this->Cities->find();

// A $city does not include the field `shape` (which is a huge polygon)
```

```
$cities = $this->Cities->find(['id', 'name', 'shape']);

// A $city now does include the `shape` property
```

I looked at the `accessible` and `hidden` properties of an entity, but these don't seem to affect the SELECT statement.

EDIT: The `selectAllExcept` query seems usefull. I combined this with the `beforeFilter` event like this:

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary)
{
    $query->selectAllExcept($this, ['shape']);
}
```

This works well for empty queries, `shape` is now excluded. But now I have no control over the other fields that might want to include or not:
`$this->Cities->find()->select(['id', 'shape'])` will then also select the other fields because the `selectAllExcept()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all except one field in cakephp 3 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719618/select-all-except-one-field-in-cakephp-3-query)

Comment: Partially, I hadn't realized the `selectAllExcept` function exists. The remaining part of my quest is how do use by default, see the examples.

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind and put that method in;

Comment: I figured that might come up, but then I won't be able to have alternative select statements in specific use cases. E.g. if use a join on this table from somewhere else and `ThisTable.id` is included because of `beforeFind`, any `SUM` or `COUNT` might break.

Comment: And how looks your code now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple overwrite `find('all')` method in your table.

For example in UsersTable:

```
public function findAll(Query $query, array $options)
{

    $query->selectAllExcept($this, ['password']);

    return $query;
}
```

then in your controller:

```
// select all except password
$users = $this->Users->find();
debug($users);
```

OR

```
// we try to select some fields, without success
$users = $this->Users->find()->select(['id', 'username', 'password']); 
debug($users);
```

OR

```
// we try to select some fields incl. password, with success
$users = $this->Users->find()->select(['id', 'username', 'password'], true); // <-- this overwrite select / selectAllExcept in custom finder
debug($users);
```

Comment: Ah, that could work too. Did you maybe make a typo? What's the difference between the last two controller lines?

Comment: last select example has second parameter, set to overwrite true. https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_select