# CakePHP 3: ->find('all') with contain not populating with associated data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, contains

I'm attempting to `->find('all')` & contain the *hasMany()* Schedules which *belongsTo()* Services within the Services controller index method. A Service can actually have zero to many Schedules. Testing and experience from the Services view method has lead me believe that the issue is due to a DB field that is using a keyword. It's a field that I cannot see a need for at this time. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to change database structure.

I attempted `->contain()` and specified the fields I wanted, including the primary fields of the Schedules contain. The results were the same as Attempt #1 listed below. I have successfully used that in another model.

I attempted `->selectAllExcept($tableObj, ['FieldToExclude'])->contain()`. I also attempted a beforeFind() within the SchedulesTable.php after research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487088/cakephp-3-exclude-fields-by-default-in-query-unless-specifically-selected) but the function never seemed to be called.

I'm able to circumvent the issue in the view method by specifying the fields in a find directly to the Services table. However, this is not a viable option within the index method. I can do a loop to get the related records, but that's timely and defeats the fantastic benefits of Cake. Contain is awesome and is exactly what I need here.

Are the belongsTo & hasMany set up incorrectly? Am I missing something in the coding of $query? I've read through the documentation and I know that I am missing what is probably obvious to so many. I know I am getting to the point of frustration that won't let me think clearly. ;) I've even stepped away for a day hoping that would help.

Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided. It will be greatly appreciated.

ServicesTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('OSCL');
    $this->setDisplayField('DocNum');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('DocNum');
    $this->belongsTo('Locations', [
                                    'className' => 'Locations', 
                                    'bindingKey' => 'Address', 
                                    'foreignKey' => 'BPShipCode',
                                    'joinType' => 'INNER'
                                ]
                    );
    $this->hasMany('Schedules', [
                                    'className' => 'Schedules', 
                                    'foreignKey' => 'SrcvCallID', 
                                    'bindingKey' => 'CallID'
                                ]
                );
}
```

And SchedulesTable.php

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;

class SchedulesTable extends Table
{   
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('SCL6');
        $this->setDisplayField('Technician'); 
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['SrcvCallID', 'Line']);
        $this->belongsTo('Services', [
                                    'className' => 'Services', 
                                    'foreignKey' => 'SrcvCallID', 
                                    'bindingKey' => 'CallID'
                                ]
                    );
    $this->hasOne('Employees', [
                                'className' => 'Employees', 
                                'foreignKey' => 'empID', 
                                'bindingKey' => 'Technician'
                            ]
                    );

    }

    /*
     Added to class after the original 3 attempts.
     Re-attempted the queries. Function made no difference.
     Debug & die within the function showed that the function was never called.
    */
    public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
    {
        return $query->selectAllExcept($this, ['Close']);
    }
}
```

Attempt #1 returns the expected # of records but the schedules array is empty. I don't get any error messages and the query log doesn't show any attempts to access the Schedules table.

```
$query = $this->Services->find('all')
                        ->where($conditions)
                        ->order([$sort => $direction])
                        ->contain(['Schedules']);
```

Debug of $query->toArray(); *The table has over 100 fields. I've removed many here for visual ease.*

```
\src\Controller\ServicesController.php (line 124)
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Service) {

        'callID' => (int) 361893,
        'subject' => 'Printer jam',
        'customer' => 'C202044',
        'custmrName' => 'Some Company',
        'contctCode' => (int) 986,
        'manufSN' => '',
        'internalSN' => '16J151800861',
        'createDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
            'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'createTime' => (int) 1612,
        'closeDate' => null,
        'closeTime' => null,
        'DocNum' => (int) 316939,
        'Series' => (int) 30,
        'schedules' => [],
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[hasErrors]' => false,
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Services'
    },
]
```

Query Log

```
SELECT 
    Services.callID AS [Services__callID], Services.subject AS [Services__subject], Services.customer AS [Services__customer], Services.custmrName AS [Services__custmrName], ... 
FROM 
    OSCL Services 
WHERE 
    (
        Services.status = 7 
        OR Services.status = -3
    ) 
ORDER BY Services.DocNum DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT 
  (
    COUNT(*)
  ) AS [count] 
FROM 
  OSCL Services 
WHERE 
  (
    Services.status = 7 
    OR Services.status = -3
  )
```

Attempt #2 generates a SQL query error "Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Close'". Makes sense because the default behavior for a model is to select all of the fields.

```
$query = $this->Services->find('all')
                        ->where($conditions)
                        ->order([$sort => $direction])
                        ->select($this->Services->Schedules);
```

Attempt #3. I tried to pass the table object to ->selectAllExcept() and exclude the problem field. The query builder builds the query incorrectly by using the fields from the Schedules table as if they were part of the Services table

```
$query = $this->Services->find('all')
                        ->where($conditions)
                        ->order([$sort => $direction])
                        ->selectAllExcept($this->Services->Schedules, ['Close'])
                        ->contain(['Schedules']);
```

Query built by the query builder. SrcvCallID, Line & Technician are all fields of the Schedules table, not Services.

```
SELECT 
    Services.SrcvCallID AS [Services__SrcvCallID], Services.Line AS [Services__Line], Services.Technician AS [Services__Technician], ... 
FROM 
    OSCL Services 
WHERE 
    (Services.status = :c0 OR Services.status = :c1) 
ORDER BY 
    Services.DocNum DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Here is an example of the expected results *manually created from the view function.*

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Service) {

        'callID' => (int) 361893,
        'subject' => 'Printer jam',
        'customer' => 'C202044',
        'custmrName' => 'Some Company',
        'contctCode' => (int) 986,
        'manufSN' => '',
        'internalSN' => '16J151800861',
        'createDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
            'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'createTime' => (int) 1612,
        'closeDate' => null,
        'closeTime' => null,
        'DocNum' => (int) 316939,
        'Series' => (int) 30,
        'schedules' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Schedule) {

            'SrcvCallID' => (int) 361893,
            'Line' => (int) 1,
            'Technician' => (int) 243,
            'StartDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-18 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'StartTime' => (int) 800,
            'EndDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-18 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'EndTime' => (int) 900,
            'U_NB_ChkInDate' => null,
            'U_NB_ChkInTime' => null,
            'U_NB_ChkOutDate' => null,
            'U_NB_ChkOutTime' => null,
            'SignData' => null,
            'Duration' => (float) 1,
            'DurType' => 'H',
            'Sched_Closed' => 'N',
            'U_NB_TechRate' => (float) 50,
            'U_NB_FollowUp' => null,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[hasErrors]' => false,
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Schedules'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Schedule) {

            'SrcvCallID' => (int) 361893,
            'Line' => (int) 2,
            'Technician' => (int) 243,
            'StartDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'StartTime' => (int) 1600,
            'EndDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'EndTime' => (int) 1630,
            'U_NB_ChkInDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'U_NB_ChkInTime' => (int) 1600,
            'U_NB_ChkOutDate' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000-04:00',
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'U_NB_ChkOutTime' => (int) 1630,
            'SignData' => null,
            'Duration' => (float) 30,
            'DurType' => 'M',
            'Sched_Closed' => 'N',
            'U_NB_TechRate' => (float) 150,
            'U_NB_FollowUp' => 'Y',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[hasErrors]' => false,
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Schedules'

        }
    ],
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[hasErrors]' => false,
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Services'
    },
]
```

Again, thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It looks like your binding key configuration is incorrect, the selected field is named `callID`, and you've configured it for the associations as `CallID`, ie with an uppercase `C` instead of a lowercase `c`. That could certainly cause the containment not to be queried, as the eager loader won't find any binding key values in the results of the main/parent query.

Comment: Thanks @ndm so much for the suggestion. Definitely something I will keep in mind for the future. I'm going to ask a very loaded question: Would you be willing to recommend an IDE that works well with Cake, MySQL & SQL Server 2014?

Comment: You're probably better off asking that over on Slack/IRC, or the forum. Personally I've been using PhpStorm for many years now, haven't touched anything else ever since.